# Deserializing an interface field from SQL

Tags: go

Let's say I have the following

```
type Stater interface{
  name()       string
  doTransition()
  driver.Valuer
}

type Session struct {
   username string
   currentState    Stater
}
```

I'm building an FSM for each user session. So each session ( The model ) should have a column in the database storing the current state. Each state is a type that implements Stater  which contains ( Name(), doTransition() and so on ) by implementing the `driver.Valuer` now the current state gets serialized correctly. What I need now is that when I fetch the session from the database the `Session.CurrentState` ( of type Stater ) get's deserialized correctly and assigned the correct concrete type. I know about the `sql.Scanner` interface but I don't know what exactly should implement it. Thank you.

Comment: An interface can be implemented by a theoretically unbound number of concrete types, so how do you suppose the deserizler should go about finding the one you *mean?*

Comment: I know, I have a map that maps the names to their types, So what I'm asking about is a clean way to implement this deserializer using this map

Comment: Have some type implementing the `database/sql.Scanner` interface. When scanning the rows, pass an instance of this type to the `Rows.Scan()` or `Row.Scan()` method for the column containing your state's data. Make the implementation deduce the actual type of the value it needs to create (using your map), create that value and populate it with the data. Have the resulting value stored in this "scanner" variable. After scanning, extract the resuting value from the "scanner" instance used for scanning, and use it.

Comment: How to create a value of a necessary type depends on your approach. A switch on the type's name is simple but static, `reflect` is complicated, slow but dynamic.

Comment: I still fail to see why you need such a complicated approach for what I'd personally consider a rather simple task. Smells like overengeneering to me.

Comment: What I ended up doing is implementing `type State struct { Stater }` which implements both the scanner and the valuer and replaced it as the type in the session. It worked fine but I just need to wrap each state I create with `State{ InitState{} }` but I guess that's fine. Is that a good design ?